# Blue color of material instead of one in texture

Tags: texturing

[image]
The inputed file is typical sand, but i can not understant how it can become blue. I suppose, that it is connected with hdri, but every single one makes the same.

Comment: It might be because you have no lighting in your scene, add a sun lamp or something.

Comment: If you are using a HDRI then you shouldnt need a sun lamp, Either your HDRI is not connected correctly, or your HDRI is a night sky or very blue hue HDRI and you are trying to mix it with a bright sunny scene. Double check HDRI is correct Try changing rotation, use different HDRI.